# Android Studio Java String Compare

Tags: java, android

I have string to compare but I can't make it to work even I searched google and stackoverflow.

So here is my code:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Najava.this,UserProfile.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_NAME,username);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Najava.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

But the activity never changes and the toast message shows up with the same string:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApJLp.png

Comment: I would compare the static string with your variable will won't break in cases of null values. However this won't fix your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that String s has un-necessary characters present.
Try below:

```
if(s.contains("success"){}
```

Note: For string comparison, its always good practice to compare constant value with other string. This will save code from Null pointers.

```
if("success".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){}
```

Comment: Gr8. Please upvote/accept if you are satisfied with the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this line before your if:

```
s = s.toLowerCase().trim();
```

or remove s from `super.onPostExecute();`